# How Can I handle Errors in PS

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I'm trying to catch the error from service restart using function. The issue Im having that catch is not doing anything through the script.

```
Function Service_Restart ($Servers, $Service){
    try {
    Write-Host "$CurrentDateTime - Restarting Service $Service on Servers $Servers"
    ForEach($Serv in $Servers){
        

            Get-Service -ComputerName $Serv -Name $Service | Restart-Service
            
        }
        
    
    } catch [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController] { 
        
        $error[0].Exception

        
}

Service_Restart Server1 ServiceName
```

I'm expecting to see an one line error not the full stack, however I see the entire error.

What I like to see as an example

```
Restart-Service : Service 'Adobe Acrobat Update Service (AdobeARMservice)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open AdobeARMservice service on computer 'Localhost'.
```

However I'm seeing

```
Restart-Service : Service 'Adobe Acrobat Update Service (AdobeARMservice)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open AdobeARMservice service on computer 'Localhost'.
At C:\user\UTILS_Version3.ps1:48 char:62
+ ...      Get-Service -ComputerName $Serv -Name $Service | Restart-Service
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

If I run  $error[0].Exception manually I get the result I'm looking for but not through the function.

```
PS C:\Users\>  $error[0].Exception

Service 'Adobe Acrobat Update Service (AdobeARMservice)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open AdobeARMservice service on computer '127.0.0.1'.
PS C:\Users\>
```

Comment: In the `catch` block, `$_` is the exception object. Try `$_.Exception`.

Comment: I tried that and its not working

Comment: Your exception type is wrong. It needs to be `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException]`

Comment: I tried that too, same result and getting the whole error stack instead one liner.

Comment: AdminOfThings' answer contains good additional information on how to identify the specific exception type to catch, but the primary problem - expecting a _non-terminating_ error to be caught with `try` / `catch` - is what makes this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `try` and `catch`, you must be working with terminating errors. Since some errors are non-terminating, you can force them to be terminating. To ensure your commands generate terminating errors, you can use the common parameter `-ErrorAction Stop`. Alternatively, you can set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and all commands within the session will implicitly apply `-ErrorAction Stop`.

In a `catch` block, `$_` or `$PSItem` is the caught `ErrorRecord` object. When handling a specific error, it is best to use the error type's full name. You can retrieve that with `$_.Exception.GetType().Fullname` in the `catch` block or `$error[0].Exception.GetType().Fullname` outside of `try {} catch {}`.

Putting this all together, you can do the following:

```
try {
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Serv -Name $Service -ErrorAction Stop |
        Restart-Service -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException] {
    $_.Exception
}
```

See [About Try Catch Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1) for more information.